# Failure after calling PKAddPaymentPassRequest handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay, wallet

I'm working on "Adding card to wallet" functionality, got all permissions related.
I'm not able to find any better documentation.

Completed the following steps

1. PKAddPaymentPassViewController with configuration(encryption type
   PKEncryptionSchemeECC_V2).
2. Received certificates, nonce and nonce
   signature, send them to the server where I received
   encryptedPassData,activationData and ephemeralPublicKey(string
   format). Created PKAddPaymentPassRequest with
   encryptedPassData,ephemeralPublicKey (bse64encoded to NSData),
   activationdata(UTF8 encoded) called handler.

Tested in TestFlight build, receiving "Could Not Add Card: Try again later or contact your card issuer for more information". Should I test only in TestFlight build?

Do I need to use any test cards to test the functionality? Let me know if I miss any steps or not followed the steps correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure that you will get a response here, as a lot of the Payment Pass documentation is private and only available under NDA.  I would suggest contacting your Apple Pay country representative and ask them to put you in touch with an engineer or other subject matter expert.

Comment: @kanna I was wondering if you were able to resolve your issue. I'm facing the same problem!

Comment: @Hamza were you able to resolve the issue, I'm facing the same

Comment: @MahendraThotakura I was able to resolve it. For us it ended up being an issue with the way we were encrypting the data that was sent back to Apple. 

It may be helpful to make sure that you're encrypting the `PKAddPaymentPassRequest` payload correctly.

Comment: @Hamza thanks for your reply, we were able to fix it